# Extract text using awk that is in between to special characters

Tags: string, bash, awk

I have the following file:

```
# cat vsrxa-1.xml

<some text>
      <source file='/PATH/vsrx.qcow2'/>
<some text>
```

I am trying to print only what is in between the ('')
Something like this:

```
<source file='/PATH/vsrx.qcow2'/>

To print only: 
/path/vsrx.qcow2

But not to print:
'/PATH/vsrx.qcow2'
```

I tried using `cat <file> | awk -F[=,] '{print $2}'`
but I only get:
`'/PATH/vsrx.qcow2'/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"'" '{print $2}' file
/PATH/vsrx.qcow2
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n "s/[^']*'\([^']*\).*/\1/p" file
/PATH/vsrx.qcow2
```